# What software to create this gif with animation effect?

Tags: gif

I'm not sure what software I should use to create this gif, which is small in size (311kb) and yet having effect like a swf video.

[image]

Photoshop is quite painful to create a gif with such effect, and window movie maker can't have these effects.

Is there any idea of what software I should use to create this gif?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe Flash can do this, unfortunately APPLE killed Flash in browsers, but this is an excellent use of it.

In order to keep the file size small you will need to limit your pallet and stick to block colours, DO NOT use gradients.

Comment: I found 2 in my computer: Adobe Flash Builder 4 and Adobe Flash Professional CS5. Which will suit best?

Comment: Flash CS5 will be perfect!

Comment: Haha, I love that, "I found 2 in my computer". Just got a computer full of expensive programs but don't know what they do or how they got there

Comment: could be a work pc.... @SaturnsEye

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft... you've just ruined the fun

Answer (score 4):

Nearly any video app can do this, i would suggest looking into:

- AfterEffects
- Flash
- Fusion
- Photoshop
- Video Paint
  etc etc

This is extremely simple animation and can therefore be done also in many more apps than normal. Its even feadible to do this frame by frame. And you could do thos even in powerpoint.

Comment: PowerPoint? Not before I have a death wish... :->

Comment: @Vincent true, but it could be done fades and moves are in its repertoare.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the above mentioned, you could still use Adobe Fireworks to create this animation.

- it is more powerful than Photoshop for creating animations (it has onion skinning, more control over the frames);
- it is better than Photoshop at manipulating vector objects.
- Apple didn't killed it (although Adobe did)

Comment: The best answer